# How can I generate an RSA pair that works both in node.js and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, rsa

I want to achieve RSA encryption between a node server and a browser.
So far I've used node-rsa on the server:

```
const RSA = require("node-rsa")
const key = new RSA({b: 512});
console.log(key.exportKey("public"))
```

And it looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAMSZQk6XJbPTr/0bY1OYQUPkUXfsC4K8
iPywjTpIDLZhw341cxPaiI0dxkP/GLvG+03xqboFMRFJbs4L5aXA9x0CAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

How can I do the same thing in browser.
P.S. I've tried SubtleCrypto API put I can't figure out how to produce a similar format as in node-rsa.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a PEM encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo or "spki" for short. Helpfully, the [official SuptleCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey#subjectpublickeyinfo_export) offers an example code snippet that shows how to create the binary structure *and* put it in PEM format.

The node-rsa NodeJS library incorrectly calls this `'pkcs8'` or more specifically `'pkcs8-public'` (at least, that's what I can grok from their documentation). [I've created bug report 208](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa/issues/208) which you can vote on.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this code for the client side that can generate an RSA pair and export the public key (for some reason it doesn't work for the private one).

```
async function exportCryptoKey(key) {
    const exportedAsBase64 = window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("spki", key))))
    return `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${exportedAsBase64}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
}
async function main(){
    keyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
            name: "RSA-OAEP",
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
            hash: "SHA-256",
        }, true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"])
    console.log(await exportCryptoKey(keyPair.publicKey))
}
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install browserify for using nodejs require() method in browser.

run this in your terminal:

```
npm install browserify
```

then,

```
browserify index.js //"your current js file_name// -o bundle.js
```

now use this bundle.js in your html